# Vue.js: List does not update when using child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having an issue when using a child component, a list does not update based on a prop passed into it.

If the `comments` array data changes, the list will not update when it uses a child component `<comment></comment>`.

TopHeader template:

```
<template>
    <ul v-for="comment in comments">

        // If don't use a child component, it updates whenever `comments` array changes:

        <li>
            <div>
                /r/{{comment.data.subreddit}} ·
                {{comment.data.score}}
            </div>
            <div class="comment" v-html="comment.data.body"></div>
            <hr>
        </li>

    </ul>
</template>
```

TopHeader component:

```
import Comment from 'components/Comment'

export default {
  name: 'top-header',
  components: {
      Comment
  },
  data () {
    return {
      username: '',
      comments: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
      fetchData: function(username){
          var vm = this;
          this.$http.get(`https://www.reddit.com/user/${username}/comments.json?jsonp=`)
          .then(function(response){
              vm.$set(vm, 'comments', response.body.data.children);
          });
      }
  }
}
```

**However, if I use a child component it does not update.**

Modified TopHeader template:

```
<template>
    <ul v-for="comment in comments">

        // If I instead use a component with prop data, it does not update
        <comment :data="comment.data"></comment>

    </ul>
</template>
```

Comment child template:

```
<template>
    <li>
        <div>
            /r/{{subreddit}} ·
            {{score}}
        </div>
        <div class="comment" v-html="body"></div>
        <hr>
    </li>
</template>
```

Comment child component:

```
export default {
  name: 'comment',
  props: ['data'],
  data() {
    return {
        body: this.data.body,
        subreddit: this.data.subreddit,
        score: this.data.score,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because of invalid tag inside `ul` tag. See [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats).

Comment: @MathewJibin is right about invalid tags into ul and li.But I don't think actual problem is here - it could be related to thing that you are assigning dynamic data inside data model, so in fact you got empty everything or undefined in your case.
Any console error ?

Comment: @MathewJibin – using `<li is="comment" :data="comment.data"></li>` still has the same issue

Comment: @BelminBedak there are no console errors. It works on the first time (setting the array), then for subsequent changes it doesn't update the view

Comment: Can you change the name of child prop from `data` to something else and see if it works?

Comment: @MathewJibin – same issue. However, if the new array has more or less elements, it "updates" but fails to replace the existing ones. E.g. if the first is [1,2,3] and the second is [4,5], then it becomes [1,2]...

Comment: Why `vm.$set`? Can you just call `vm.comments.push.apply(vm.comments,response.body.data.children)` ?

Comment: nvm saw your update - still fails to update

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any error? Can you change name of the `comment` variable or `comment` tag to something else and try? Recreate a fiddle with your problem if problem persists.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the stuff returned in data() in the child component. If I use the direct prop as in `{{ data.subreddit }}`, it is updated. However using the data func props doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

Move the `v-for` statement to the component `<comment>`. With the `v-for` on the ul-tag you would repeat the ul tag. See http://codepen.io/tuelsch/pen/YNOqYR again for an example.

```
<div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="fetch">Fetch data</button>
    <ul>
        <comment v-for="comment in comments" v-bind:comment="comment" />
    </ul>
</div>
```